Opamp circuit line
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[op amp] (opamp1) {}
(opamp1.-) to[R, l=$R_1$] (-2,0) node[ground] {}
(opamp1.+) -- (-2,-2) node[ground] {}
(opamp1.out) -- (2,0) to[R, l=$R_f$] (2,2) node[ground] {}
(-2,0) node[left] {$v_1$}
(2,0) -- (2.5,0) node[right] {$v_{\text{out1}} = -18v_1$}
(0,-4) node[op amp] (opamp2) {}
(opamp2.-) to[R, l=$R_2$] (-2,-4) node[ground] {}
(opamp2.+) -- (-2,-6) node[ground] {}
(opamp2.out) -- (2,-4) to[R, l=$R_f$] (2,-2) node[ground] {}
(-2,-4) node[left] {$v_2$}
(2,-4) -- (2.5,-4) node[right] {$v_{\text{out2}} = -15v_2$}
(0,-8) node[op amp] (opamp3) {}
(opamp3.-) to[R, l=$R_3$] (-2,-8) node[ground] {}
(opamp3.+) -- (-2,-10) node[ground] {}
(opamp3.out) -- (2,-8) to[R, l=$R_f$] (2,-6) node[ground] {}
(-2,-8) node[left] {$v_3$}
(2,-8) -- (2.5,-8) node[right] {$v_{\text{out3}} = -24v_3$}
(2.5,0) -- (4,0)
(2.5,-4) -- (4,-4)
(2.5,-8) -- (4,-8)
(4,0) -- (4,-4) -- (4,-8) -- (4,-10) node[ground] {}
(4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$v_{\text{out}} = 18v_1 - 15v_2 - 24v_3$}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{array}


Can you clarify what problem you face?

Welcome! Are you able to make your code compilable?

Welcome to TeX.SE!
To long for comment ...

it is not clear what your picture should present
result of compiling of your code fragment gives strange result
I just guess that part of image around operational amplifier can be something like this:

\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
   
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} 
\draw   (0,0)   node[op amp, anchor=-] (OA1) {}
        (OA1.-) to[R=$R_1$]     (-2,0)      node[ground] {}
        (OA1.+) -| (0,-2) node[ground] {}
        (OA1.out)   to[R=$R_f$, *-] ++ (0,-2)   node[ground] {}
        (OA1.out)  to[short,-o]     ++ (1, 0)   node[right] {$v_1$}
%        (2,0) -- (2.5,0) node[right] {$v_{\text{out1}} = -18v_1$}
;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}

which hasn't much sense.


For further help please provide sketch of desired result and extend your code fragment to MWE (Minimal Working Example) similar to showed above.

